# What to do when external service to validate data fails?

Tags: php, validation, external

Let's say we have a system that needs to validate data using a third party system. For example, we allow user registration and we validate the provided email address using an external system that tell us if the email is valid, if it is a temporary email etc, etc.

Our system receives the email address, makes a request in real time to the third party email validation system and, depending on the response (email valid or not) it will allow the user to register.

My question is: What happens if something goes wrong with the connection? (timeout, DNS errors, etc). I think it will be wrong to allow the user to continue the registration process because we don't know if the email is valid but, at the same time, we can't stop the registration process because the email might be valid.

I'm thinking in trying the connection more than once (let's say, three times). If it fails, then return an error code with a message like "Please try again later". Is this the right approach to this problem?

Thanks in advance :D

Answer (score 0):

You treat this the same way as if any other sub-system on the server failed, e.g. the database being down: [`500 Internal Server Error` or `503 Service Unavailable`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes#5xx_Server_error). Whether you want to try more than once before giving up is up to you.

Answer (score 0):

It all depends on what kind of system you are working with. If you are confident that the Users will definitely comeback to your site later and register this approach is fine.

But in Today's world there are so many web services out there and the users are great assets, you wouldn't want to loose them or their data. You can always collect the data and store it in a staging table and later if you can run some Schedules tasks every 5 mins or add them to a queue service to validate the data with this 3rd party and finally store it in appropriate way and send them a notification about their account being active. This way the User experience when they use your web page will be great and they would come back (a second win is you can actually verify their email account)